# How does the computer determine where to write in the virtual memory?

Tags: memory, paging

I am trying to answer this question: Why is the page size equal to the offset of a memory address?

Is it because the computer determine the page number from the page table and then multiply that by the offset to determine where to start writing? I think it's the only logical explanation possible, but I am not sure, because the tutor couldn't answer me.

Also, if you have a 64 bit addressable memory and the offset takes like 14 bits, isn't the 14 bits wasted? You can allocate your data to more memory location without the offset, am I right?

Comment: Your tutor _couldn't_ answer you? Get a better tutor!

Comment: Yeah, I don't even know why I paid the guy.

Comment: The question does not really make sense. Please check Jimbo's Big Bag of Trivia at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Answer (score 0):

Because the offset is the only part of a virtual address that is not translated (translated here means that the value changes) into a physical address. Roughly speaking, a virtual address is formed by a base address and an offset. The base address is translated into an address to the start of a physical page. These pages have to be sized so that any offset from the original virtual address lies within that page. This is the reason why page size - 1 equals max offset.

For example: on x86 systems using tables with 4MB pages (attribute PS on bit 7 of the page descriptor is 1), the base address is formed by the 10 most significant bits, which point to one of possible 1024 page entries in the Page Directory. Each entry is 32 bits long (a Page Descriptor). If the Page Descriptor refers to a 4MB page as indicated, then there is a field that stores the first physical address of that 4MB page into physical memory (commonly referred as page frame).

Within that page frame, a 22 offset is needed to address all and every single byte in the page. That offset is taken directly from the 22 less significant bits of the virtual address.